# Case Statement not exporting variable

Tags: bash, syntax, case, glob

I am having issues with my case statement not returning values.  I am new to using cases and not a computer programmer.  Any advice is helpful

```
############################# Chose GrADS or OpenGrADS #########################
while true; do
  read -p "Would you like to install OpenGrADS or GrADS? (OpenGrADS/GrADS)" yn
  case $yn in
    [OpenGrADS]* )
      export GRADS_PICK=1    #variable set for grads or opengrads choice
      break
      ;;
    [GrADS]* )
      export GRADS_PICK=2   #variable set for grads or opengrads choice
      break
      ;;
    * )
    echo " "
    echo "Please answer OpenGrADS or GrADS (case sensative).";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: What do you think `[OpenGrADS]*` means?

Comment: The users selected input they they enter from the read statement???

Comment: No, it means *one* of the characters in the brackets, followed by any number of any other character. If you want an exact match, drop the brackets and the `*`. (As an aside, `yn` suggests you are expecting a yes/no response, not the name of the thing to install.)

Comment: Run `PAGER='less +/^\ *pattern\ matching' man bash` look under the `special pattern` The brackets has a special meaning for `regex` and the shell's pattern matching. It is not just for decoration/eye candy stuff.

Comment: @Jetchisel These are not regexes; they are *patterns*.

Comment: Right, I just mentioned the `regex` part out of nowhere.

Comment: You need to quote `[]` characters. I'd recommend using select instead: `select pick in opengrads grads; do [[ $pick ]] && break; echo "$REPLY: invalid input" >&2; done`. `$pick` is set to selected word, the number is available in `$REPLY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, your mistake was how you checked the input. Be careful with * because it's a special character in most of the programming languages and especially bash/unix.

```
while read -p "Would you like to install OpenGrADS or GrADS? (OpenGrADS/GrADS)" yn; do

  case $yn in
  OpenGrADS)
    echo "first choice"
    export GRADS_PICK=1    #variable set for grads or opengrads choice
    break
    ;;
  GrADS)
    echo "second choice"
    export GRADS_PICK=2   #variable set for grads or opengrads choice
    break
    ;;
   * )
   echo " "
   echo "Please answer OpenGrADS or GrADS (case sensative).";;
esac
done
```

EDIT: quotes aren't necessary. (thanks chepner and Gordon Davisson)

Comment: The quotes are harmless but unnecessary in this case. `OpenGrADS` would work just as well as `"OpenGrADS"`.

Comment: Quoting is not needed to make strings in shell syntax (things are almost always strings by default); what quoting does is control/disable the special meanings of characters inside the quotes. For example, in a glob pattern, `*` matches any string, but `"*"`, `'*'`, and `\*` only match a literal asterisk character.